# Google Spreadsheet API - WorksheetEntry becomes Read Only?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I've created a small program (in C#) that pushes data to a Google Spreadsheet and it adds/removes rows as it needs to but for some reason after a while the WorksheetEntry that I am using suddenly becomes read-only and the only way to fix it seems to manually go to the Spreadsheet and overwrite the headers by hand. Is there another way to go about this?

Example of the problem: (It fails on .Update() due to it becoming read only)

```
m_SongsSheet = (WorksheetEntry)m_SongSpreadSheet.Worksheets.Entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title.Text.ToLower() == "songlist");
m_SongsSheet.Rows = 10;
m_SongsSheet.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a note in the Manage Worksheets page of the documentation that states

> Note: User access levels are set in the GUI. If a user owns a given worksheet or is listed as an editor, then they have read/write access; if they're listed only as a viewer, then they have read-only access. In addition, if the worksheet is published then even unauthenticated users and users not listed as viewers have read access.

Make sure that you (or who is authenticated in your application) is set as an editor for you to have write access as well.